# Getting gender count from one table and inserting to another in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take gender stats from table 1
[table_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSReI.png)

and table 2
[table_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndQGX.png)
and insert into 'gender' table
[gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piEqd.png)
using the command :

`INSERT INTO gender(Male) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Male'),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE Gender = 'Male'))`

and

`INSERT INTO gender(Female) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Female'),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE Gender = 'Female'))`

But i keep getting an error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of your question, delete the external links, and instead show us clear input and output data.

Comment: Do you want to insert two rows?

Comment: Yes @Schwern i want to insert data from each tables as rows

Comment: Comment noted @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of values passed and the number columns in the gender table don't match, hence the error.

Assuming the table gender has following columns -> gender, count_1, count_2

> INSERT INTO gender(gender, count_1, count_2)  VALUES ('Male', (SELECT
> COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Male'),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
> table_2 WHERE Gender = 'Male'))
>
> INSERT INTO gender(gender, count_1, count_2) VALUES ('Female', (SELECT
> COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Female'),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
> table_2 WHERE Gender = 'Female'))

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling your insert expects rows with one column, but your value has two.

```
INSERT INTO gender(Male) VALUES (  -- start of a row
  -- Column 1
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Male'),
  -- Column 2
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE Gender = 'Male')
) -- end of a row
```

The problem is you have an extra set of parens making it one row with two columns. If you want to insert two rows, remove those parens.

```
INSERT INTO gender(Male) VALUES
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Male'), -- row 1
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE Gender = 'Male'); -- row 2
```

The parens go around each row.

Comment: its shows error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE Gender = 'Male'),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab...' at line 1"

Comment: Replace COUNT() with COUNT(*)